# Magento 2 There are many page visits with duplicate “/storecode” , in google Analytics:

Tags: magento2

**It only happens for product pages. Checking Google Analytics for a sample page showed the user came from magento’s search results:**

> how to remove this multiple store code from my magento 2 store

http://prntscr.com/p24602

[image]

Comment: This looks like a configuration issue. You need to cross check your configurations. Post screens related to configuration to comment further.

Comment: are you talking about web configuration.please check this i am sharing with you

Comment: As i see screenshot, there is not an option for setup storecode, so finally, we have to go for customization part. You need to check in code. 
Please track the place from where your url is processing to google.

Comment: how the google analytic take  url from magento store can you please assist me